# If dim(ker(T1)) = dim(ker(T2)) and ker(T1) subset of ker(T2), prove Ker(T1) = Ker(T2) and T1 = λT2

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let V be finite dimensional vector space over R such that dim(V ) ⩾ 1. Let T1 : V −→ R and T2 : V −→ R be two non-zero linear transformations such that ker(T1) ⊆ ker(T2). Prove that (i) ker(T1) = ker(T2). (ii) T1 = λT2 for some real number λ ̸= 0.

Using the rank-nullity theoram I managed to prove dimensions of the kernels are equal and after some googling I figured out if dimensions are equal and one is subset of another then both the subspaces are equal but I don't really understand how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $T_1\neq 0$ there exists $v_0$ such that $T_1v_0=1.$ Then
$T_1[v-(T_1v)v_0]=0.$ Hence $T_2[v-(T_1v)v_0]=0,$ which implies $T_2v=(T_2v_0)\,T_1v.$ Thus $T_2=(T_2v_0)T_1.$ As $T_2\neq 0,$ we have $T_2v_0\neq 0.$ In particular $\ker T_1=\ker T_2.$

Comment: is there a prove for why kerT1 = kerT2

Comment: If $T_2=\mu T_1,$ $\mu\neq 0,$ then the kernels coincide. In the answer $\mu=T_2v_0.$

Comment: i got the ii part of the ques but i am sorry i am not able to grasp the 1st one 
is there a standalone proof for how ker(T1) = Ker(T2)

Comment: Part $(ii)$ implies $(i).$

Comment: ohk Thanks a lot!!